# Can I use CSS to make one element visually identical to another in font size, weight, etc.?

Tags: html, css

So let's say I have a DIV tag:

```
<div class="testHead"></div>
```

I want to for all intents and purposes be visually identical to the `<h1>` tag for font look and feel, because there'd be some issues actually using the `<h1>` tag.  Is there an easy way to set this up in CSS? HTML5/CSS3 is perfectly ok here.

Comment: What sort of issues are you experiencing with using the <h1> tag?

Comment: Aside from the semantic meaning heading elements have, most browsers simply style the font to be large and bold, and that can easily be altered with a CSS reset. Are you having an issue changing the font properties via CSS?

Comment: Elements come preloaded with CSS. You can find these in your browsers developer tools. You can create a class for all the `<h1>` CSS. However, I  kind of miss the point in doing something like this when an element already comes preloaded.

Comment: If you fully emulate the CSS for an `<h1>` on a `<div>`, it will probably have all the same issues that you are encountering when just using a plain old `<h1>`

Comment: Well the issue is that we have a server-side script that renders HTML using the <h1> tag all over the page to render in the proper font, and then another script nearby that renders HTML using the <h1> tag that we now want to look differently.  Rather than trying an overriding the styles for H1 and wreck both, I'm trying to figure out a way to seperate the styles completely to accommodate future changes, one looking like <h1> for now and the other one just slightly different from <h1>.

Comment: For the sake of avoiding jQuery and JavaScript for something that can easily be accomplished with CSS alone, refer to `user20561`'s second portion of his or her answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: **No, you can't emulate the style of another element in CSS.**
A few alternatives:

- Use **javascript/jQuery** to copy all the computed styles of another element. See this question for more information: [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)
- **Manually copy** the computed styles from the developer view ("Inspect Element") of an element into the new element's css.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "you can't emulate the style of another element in CSS".

Comment: I'm using the question author's terminology: "emulate" means (I believe) to copy all styles of one element to another one.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but ...

Well, you could, kindof - in your CSS, you could add the `.testHead` to your `h1` selector:

`h1, .testHead {properties: here}`

Or, more elegantly - if you have control over your markup, as well:

`h1, .h1 {properties: here}`

and in your HTML:

`<div class="testHead h1"></div>`